# Google-App Engine logging problem

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced problems with Google-App Engine's logging facility. Everything was working fine for me until this morning, I ran my local server and no logging messages were being displayed (well, none of my logging messages, the server GET messages etc.. are being displayed). Even errors are not being reported. I have no idea what is going on.

If this has happened to anyone, can you please advise on how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using pydev plugin for eclipse?

Comment: No, just the standard command line.

Comment: I think there are two instances running and you are seeing the wrong one

Comment: No, I only have one instance running. Also I tried restarting my computer in case there was a lock on a required file or something but that didn't help either.

Comment: trying running the application using appengine sdk on a different port . I think there is some problem with default port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Abdul you made me realize what the problem is. I had changed a URL in my application to point to the application that I had deployed to Google-App Engine. It should have been pointing to my local application. I had myapp.appspot.com/move instead of localhost/move

Comment: Always have a separate copy of application while uploading to avoid these mishaps.

Answer (score 0):

In Dev server The only one and best way is:

http://localhost:8080/?debug

:)